# Laravel and Ajax update not allowed

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

I'm working on a CRUD in Laravel with Ajax requests and it works just fine till I stumbled upon an error on the update of a model. 
When clicking in the edit button, the modal window loads all the data of an employee and when I edit anything Ajax will throw an error saying that two of the fields are requested even if they are filled.

This is the error thrown in the console:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"email\":[\"The email field is requested.\"],\"fullname\":[\"The fullname field is requested.\"]}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "email": [
      "The email field is requested."
    ],
    "fullname": [
      "The fullname field is requested."
    ]
  },
  "status": 422,
  "statusText": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

This is the Ajax function:

```
/* Edit employee */
$(document).on('click', '#btn-edit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'put',
        url: link + id,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // data: new FormData($("#form-employee")[0]),
        data: $("#form-employee").serializeArray(),
        success: function() {
            $('#btn-update').click();
            $('#employeeModal').modal('hide');
            swal(i18n.buttons.updated_msg, i18n.employees.updated_alert, "success");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $('.alert ul').empty();
            $('.alert').show();
            $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
                $('.alert ul').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                $('#' + key).parent('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            });
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And the Laravel validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email'             => 'required|email|unique:employees,email,' . $this->employee,
        'fullname'          => 'required|string|min:4|max:255',
        'password'          => 'nullable|min:6',
        'phone_number'      => 'nullable|numeric|digits_between:0,50',
        'profile_picture'   => 'nullable|image',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've had an issue with these type of forms and PUT requests, I'm guessing you are also uploading files in the form?

I'd suggest trying a POST instead to see if it works (the route will need updated too).

Aside from that, it'd be helpful to see the data that is being sent in the ajax request.

Comment: The form is being prepared for uploading files too yes. Is that the problem?
In the ajax request Im not sending anything new. For instance; I click the edit employee button and all the data is loaded in the form, then I click Save with no changes and itll throw the 'fields required' error even if Im sending the same values that are already on the db

Comment: the file upload part isn't a problem, but I am guessing the request type is, so I'd swap `put` with `post` and the same in your route file and see if that works.

Comment: My route is using the Laravel resource:
`Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');`
Should I remove that?

Comment: I think you might have to actually, the default for updating a model is `put` but (I believe) you need to use `post`, so something like `Route::post('employees/{id}', 'EmployeesController@update');` and also list your other routes for crud actions for that model manually too.

Comment: I dont know how but it worked like a charm. Do you know why is this happening? What's the difference here between using post / put?

Comment: I'm not sure why to be honest, I think it may be down to multipart/form-data not being visible in php://input if the method is PUT. You might be able to use a hidden input like `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">` to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your input have the same name defined as in the backend?

Comment: Yes, they have.